# Is there any difference between var a = something and window.a = someting?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, global-object

I'm new to the JavaScript World and I'm confused after I knew a lot about **the global object** (usually window) and knew it's just an object like any object I'd create and that **var** set properties in the global object unlike let

after that
**Is there any difference between window.a = something (*like in any object*) and var a = something?**

Comment: in the global context, nothing significant that I can think of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the global context, using `var` vs assigning to `window` are indeed quite similar. However, *yes* there are a number of differences. Here are a few I can think of:

---

- `var` declarations are *hoisted*, which means that you can use a variable declared with `var` before you've declared it. On the other hand, trying to use something assigned to `window` before that assignment has occurred will produce a `ReferenceError`:

```js
// This is okay. The variable declaration is hoisted, so you can use it before
// it's been declared (although it won't be assigned its value until later).
console.log(a);
var a = "hello world";
```

```js
// On the other hand, without var, this creates an error.
console.log(a);
window.a = "hello world";
```

---

- Variables declared with `var` cannot be removed from the global object, but simple assignments to `window` can be removed:

```js
var a = "hello world";

console.log(a);
delete window.a; // Does nothing for `var`.
console.log(a);
```

```js
window.a = "hello world";

console.log(a);
delete window.a; // This will delete it, further access creates a ReferenceError.
console.log(a);
```

---

- And, of course, `var` declarations are scoped to the current execution context. In the global scope, this doesn't differ from assigning to `window`, but within a function, a `var` will disappear when the function returns.

```js
function foo() {
  var a = "hello world";
  console.log(a);
}

foo();
console.log(a); // ReferenceError
```

```js
function foo() {
  window.a = "hello world";
  console.log(a);
}

foo();
console.log(a); // still exists here
```

---

Comment: OK, but like you say in the third difference var declarations are scoped to the current execution context. but window is not. **Why when assigning a value to something without declaring it with var creates a global object (inside a container of course)? is this equal to window.something**
@crice

Comment: Yes, assigning a value to an *undeclared* variable is the same as assigning to `window` for the most part. However, *when in strict mode*, the former will be an error but the latter is still allowed. If you're not in strict mode, then the two are the same afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You use `window.a =` if you want the variable `a` global. This means that any JS code has access to this variable. While the `var a =` is the commonly used way to declare a variable. In this case, the variable is only accessible inside its container.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, except for in Node.js, where having `a = 5` or `var a = 5` (along with `let` and `const`) will not assign the value to `global.a`. You have to explicitly say `global.a = 5`.